# how to add options in combobox in C# from mysql database column

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I have a combo box in my windows application form. I have a table called menu-list in a MySQL database. When i click on the combo box i want the options to be the value of a particular row of the database table for example a row called wine has 2 values, for example red wine and white wine, so when i click on the combo box i want the options to be red wine and white wine

```
private void menustart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cmsDataSet.menulist' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.menulistTableAdapter.Fill(this.cmsDataSet.menulist);

}
```

I used the above code but it didnt work

Comment: igore that i was just copy pasting something from the net which didn't workout.. could you help me with an easier way to achieve my desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some of these posts might help you to get a solution :

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158936/c-sharp-mysql-query-result-to-combobox) 
[Solution 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/525f9b18-ffe7-4242-a0a9-80137b85cb25/filling-in-a-combobox-from-database?forum=csharpgeneral) 
[Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154547/wpf-combo-box-populate-data-from-mysql-database)

Try these and let me know if you could find a solution.

EDIT : Try this code.

```
string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                     "DATABASE=yourDB;" +
                     "UID=root;" +
                     "PASSWORD=yourPassword;";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
string command = "select wine from menu-list";
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command,connection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   string wine = string.Format("{0}", row.Item[0]);
   yourCombobox.Items.Add(wine);
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: thanks alot worked perfectly as i wanted..there is another thing that i wanted to do.. could you tell  me how to add these values retrived from the database as a checkbox option within a combobox.

Comment: @Brian I don't understand... What do you want to do ? Could you be more specific about your question ? Do you want to do the same for checkboxes ?

Comment: ya sure now in the solution which u provided every value from the database table is going into the combo box from which i can select only 1 value. i need to select multiple values from the combo box(ie try to 1st convert those values into a check box list and then but that check box list in the combo box) is that possible?? o is there any alternate solution

Comment: @Brian I think what you're trying to do might be solved here, it is using ComboBox, and they put some CheckBox within the ComboBox. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF